# Android titanium App crashes after using on-screen nav bar

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have created an app using titanium appcelerator, the app uses a tab group. when i use the hardware nav buttons on a samsung galaxy it works fine, however when I enable the on-screen nav bar and disable the hardware buttons the app crashes every time I start it. I have been trying to find the error and fix the problem for months now with no luck. The app crashes on devices that have no hardware nav buttons also.

Titanium SDK = 3.5.1GA

Android version on phone = 5.0.2

please help, thanks in advance.

this is the error i get :

```
[WARN] :   ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f020074 (t=1 e=116) (error -75)
[DEBUG] :  AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 1036
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:     Resource ID #0x7f020074
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1310)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:790)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:770)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:746)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiUIHelper.getResourceDrawable(TiUIHelper.java:902)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiUIHelper.getResourceDrawable(TiUIHelper.java:897)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiFileHelper.loadDrawable(TiFileHelper.java:306)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiFileHelper.loadDrawable(TiFileHelper.java:289)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.MenuItemProxy.handleSetIcon(MenuItemProxy.java:31   5)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.MenuItemProxy.setIcon(MenuItemProxy.java:333)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.MenuProxy.handleAdd(MenuProxy.java:176)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.MenuProxy.handleMessage(MenuProxy.java:61)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.kroll.common.TiMessenger.dispatchMessage(TiMessenger.java:389)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.kroll.common.TiMessenger.dispatchPendingMessages(TiMessenger.j ava:374)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.kroll.common.TiMessenger$2.getResult(TiMessenger.java:252)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.kroll.common.TiMessenger.sendBlockingMessage(TiMessenger.java: 286)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.kroll.common.TiMessenger.sendBlockingRuntimeMessage(TiMesseng  er.java:186)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Function.call(V8Function.java:46)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiMenuSupport.onCreateOptionsMenu(TiMenuSupport.ja   va:43)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(TiBaseActivity.java:852    )
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2820)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:2   24)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.  java:232)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarA    ctivityDelegateICS.java:146)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:1 99)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCre atePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:599)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow. java:968)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:308)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error generated is Resources$NotFoundException. From the exception stack it is coming from onCreateOptionsMenu, which means that while clicking on the option menu the error is getting generated. On the option menu, you are referencing a resource with the ID 0x7f020074 which is not present. To get the mapping, refer to R.java file in the build folder and you can get an idea or go through the menu code.